# Taking a Picture from Web Browser

Tags: javascript, android, windows, browser, camera

I am trying to find a way to take a picture from the camera of a netbook (Win7 or Android) inside a web browser(either chrome, firefox or ie). After that I want to take that image as a file(or binary) back into the web browser.

Is this possible? or does anyone have a code sample for a similar situation like this?

Assume that user agrees to give all the privileges that are required.

Regards,
sakal

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to access the webcam using Javascript only. However, it's possible through flash. Have a look on this: http://blog.vamapaull.com/?p=355.

Comment: Now it is with [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NavigatorUserMedia.getUserMedia).